# Defaulting KClass class type in kotlin function argument

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to default `errorClass` in my function so that I can pass in only one parameter. I tried the format below but I get compilation error around `= StandardError::class`.

are we able to do it easily without introducing another function?

```kotlin
fun <V, E : TypedError> functionName(message: String = "Message", errorClass: KClass<E> = StandardError::class, action: () -> V){
...
}

interface TypedError

data class StandardError(val code: Int) : TypedError
```

Comment: `fun <V> functionName(message: String = "Message", errorClass: KClass<out TypedError> = StandardError::class,  action: () -> V){ //...
}`

Comment: @IR42 That works like a charm, but what was the problem in defining that thing just like how OP defined?

Comment: You can't have a default type for a generic type.

Comment: @IR42, thanks! post it as an answer and I will accept it!